# Breeze Cannot return extended Entities using queries that have an .expand clause in Breeze 1.4.14

Tags: javascript, sql, breeze, entity-framework-6

I am now using Breeze 1.1.14, previously I was previously using Breeze 1.1.11.
When I used Breeze 1.1.11, I could use an extended Entity and a query with a `.expand` clause and my result set would contain the extended Entity.  With Breeze 1.1.14, this is no longer the case.  If I use an `.expand` clause, I will only return the non-Extended portion of the Entity.

Here is an example:
First declare the extended Entity:

```
var projectAugmented = function() {
    this.LastFirstName = ko.observable("");
    this.ProjectNameTemp = ko.observable("");
    this.flushYesNo = ko.observable(false);
};

metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("tblProjects", projectAugmented);
```

Then create a function that uses the extended entity:

```
var getProject = function(projectName) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var predicate = new breeze.Predicate("ProjectName", "==", projectName);
    var qry = new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("GetProject")
        .where(predicate)
        .expand("tblProjects_Techs, tblProjects_GSIDs, tblProjects_Customers, tblLogBook");

    manager.executeQuery(qry.using())
        .then(function(r) {

            deferred.resolve(r.results);
        })
        .fail(qryFailed);

    function qryFailed(e) {
        deferred.reject(new Error(e));
    }

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

If I run the query using Breeze 1.4.14, the query will not return any of the extended Entity values. If I remove the .expand clause, the query will return the extended Entity values. This functionality existed in Breeze 1.4.11. Is this a bug, or a new feature in Breeze 1.4.14. If it is a new feature, then where is it documented?

Comment: has that been solved? Do you have solutions to this so far? I stumbled across the same problem as you did as well.

Answer (score 1):

We have done nothing intentional to change the behavior that you expect. I hate to belabor the obvious but in so many of these cases it turns out that a change in application code accounts for misadventure rather than a change to Breeze version.

So humor me, please, and confirm your claim with absolute certainty. By this I mean that you take the **exact same code** and show that **swapping v.1.4.14 for 1.4.11 alone causes the problem**.

FWIW, you can simplify your custom constructor by omitting the observables. Simple property definitions will do.

```
var projectAugmented = function() {
    this.LastFirstName = "";
    this.ProjectNameTemp = "";
    this.flushYesNo = false;
};
```

If you can confirm that something is amiss with 1.4.14, I'm curious if the simplified constructor makes a difference.

### Incidentals

You do not need to do your own promise work with the likes of `deferred`. The breeze query methods you're using already return promises.

```
var getProject = function(projectName) {
    return new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("GetProject")
        .where("ProjectName", "==", projectName)
        .expand("tblProjects_Techs, tblProjects_GSIDs, tblProjects_Customers, tblLogBook")
        .using(manager).execute()
        .then(function(data) {return data.results;});
        // no need for your fail clause because it's work is already in a failed promise from breeze
};
```

See how crisp that is without the superfluous promise dreck?

Comment: Per your request, I used the exact code twice with the only exception being that the Breeze modules were upgraded from v.1.4.11 to v.1.4.14. With Breeze v.1.4.11, the application ran correctly.  With Breeze v.1.4.14, I encountered the same problem that I initially reported.  I also used your FWIW recommendations and encountered the same problem.

Comment: To perform the Breeze upgrade, I upgraded the following modules: Breeze Client - Javascript, Breeze Server - ContextProvider, Breeze Server - for Web API 2, Breeze Server - ContextProvicer for Entity Framework 6, and Breeze Client and Server - Javascript client with ASP.NET Web API 2 and Entity Framework 6.  Thank you for your help with this application.  I apologize for the poor formatting of my reply, but this is my first Stack Overflow post.  I have been working on this problem for several hours.  My application uses Durandal, Knockout, and Breeze and is a bit complex.

Comment: However, all my debugging efforts seem to indicate, the source of the problem in my application appears to be the upgrade of Breeze from v.1.4.11 to v.1.4.14.

Comment: Well that narrows the field. There are some procedures described in ["Query Result Debugging"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-result-debugging) to pursue. First I'd confirm that the related entity data are on the wire; browser network tools should reveal that quickly. Then I'd pay particular attention to the corresponding related entity types in the `manager.metadataStore`. You might share one of them in an update ... that and the navigation property from `Project` to that entity. Something might pop out of that.

Comment: @Ward Kudos for the great `breezejs` library, however I ran onto the same problem as what he faced, and currently I'm using v 1.5.0, my navigational property doesn't return `extended entities` when I was doing `expand()`

Comment: @Ward However when I'm trying with `obj.entityAspect.loadNavigation('prop')`... it works like charm.

Comment: @Roylee Please follow the link I provided to learn how to debug your query. If that fails, please open your own stack overflow question with more specific details including query and pertinent model.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to the problem.  When I looked at the packages folder connected to my application, I saw that I had Version 1.4.12 and Version 1.4.14 Breeze modules.  I found this interesting because the original version of the application before I tried to upgrade to Breeze 1.4.14 contained Breeze 1.4.11 and Breeze 1.4.12 modules.

The solution was to delete all 'Breeze' modules from the packages folder.  I then ran a Clean Solution on my Visual Studio 2013 environment.  I then reloaded the 'Breeze' modules using the NuGet Package Manager.  After I loaded the Breeze 1.4.14 modules, the packages fold only contained Breeze 1.4.14 modules.

After loading the Version 1.4.14 Breeze modules, I still had a significant amount of work to do because the syntax of Version 1.4.11 Breeze is different from Version 1.4.14 Breeze.

I had to replace all instances of [Queryable] with [EnableQuery] in BreezeController.cs.  I also had to replace all instances of IQueryable<> with IEnumerable<>.  Once these changes were made, I rebuilt the application and the application worked properly.